# clang-format: All conditions on same line or all on new line

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

Assuming the following code example, either I want all conditions on a single line, if it's under `ColumnLimit` or all conditions in their own line if `ColumnLimit` is reached.

```
if (loc.latitude > 90.0f || loc.latitude < -90.0f || loc.longitude > 180.0f || loc.longitude < -180.0f ||
    1241312312412 > 13231231241232) {
    return false;
}
```

Is there any configuration for that? I've only found this for function parameters with `BinPackArguments` and `BinPackParameters`.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate is basically "No", but maybe you could request future support for a feature such as this one.

Comment: @dfri This makes me sad :(

Comment: Yes I like clang-format, but when I find features I found lacking, I feel the same ... (E.g. that me wanting `void foo(const T& obj)` formatting means I'll have to accept `void bar(T* p)` formatting rather than `void bar(T *p)`).

Comment: @dfri I'm on clang-format's side on that one :P

Comment: But we should at least have the option of deviating from the default case! :)